# Access to hangfire dashboard using Angular/WebApi

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, hangfire

Im trying to setup hangfire for a new dot net core project. It is based on the WebApi / Angular template in Visual studio. After installing hangifre and adding these lines:

app.UseHangfireServer();
   app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire");

but the /hangfire will just redirect to the start page of the Angular.

Any idea how to use access the dashboard?

Comment: You should give more info. How routing is set up? What .NET Core/Framework are you using? Likely this route is already taken (overriden) by some other setting.

Comment: You are right. I worked it out by changing the order the routes were being set up. Load the hangfire before the SPA

Answer (score 1):

Load the hangfire before the SPA

Startup:

```
//Hangfire
app.UseHangfireDashboard();

//SPA
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
    // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }

});
```